# Positioning text inside a button

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, positioning

I have buttons with text in it which has too much space above it. Is looks like this:

[image]

How can I position the text a little bit higher so that it doesn't get sliced by the border of the button?

HTML:

`<input type="button" value="a">`

Here is my CSS so far:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
  min-width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

The `line-height` property doesn't change anything, even with the use of `!important`.

Comment: But line-height is what you want. ;) Use a smaller value than your font-size.

Comment: I thouhgt that lineheight is what I want, but I want the font size this big and the buttons this small. Is there no way to move the text indepent from the button?

Comment: You can have `font-size: 30px;` and then for example `line-height: 20px;`. Play around a bit. This should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a fixed height will throw the alignment off.
Setting the font size will be enough for the div to auto-size and the text will be centered.
Try this new css:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
  min-width: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to preserve the fixed width and height of the button and the font size of the text then you could do something like below.
This is putting the text in a different div so you can position it on top of the button.
If the button is position: relative, the text div is position: absolute, and the HTML is structured so the text div is within the button tag, then it will layer nicely.
Also, when done this way the text will move with the button and won't be displaced (if say you give the button a margin: 100px).

```
<button value="">
    <div id="buttonText">a</div>
</button>

Here is my CSS so far:

<style>
button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#buttonText
{
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    left: 9px;
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>
```